# Referencing between two tables SQL?

Tags: sql

I have two tables and I am trying to count the number of times a particular 'ID' occurs and then output a name that corresponds with that 'id'. For example, certain people within the list have multiple occurring IDs, and I want to output the people whose IDs occur more than 4 times.

Thanks to bvr, I have one part of it, I now know how to display the Values that occur more than 4 times, by using the following statement:

```
SELECT ID , COUNT(OrderID) FROM Table1
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(OrderID) > 4
```

Just need the second part.

Here is an example of the two tables.

Table 1

```
ID | OrderID
--------------
191 | 1020
150 | 1090
191 | 1023
140 | 1033
191 | 2132
191 | 1233
191 | 1321
```

Table 2

```
ID | FirstName
--------------
191 | Mat
150 | Stewart
191 | Mat
140 | John
191 | Mat
191 | Mat
191 | Mat
```

I want to output something like this

```
Occurrences  | FirstName 
-------------------------
         5   |  Mat
```

Comment: Why does Table 2 have all those duplicate lines? You need to normalize your schema.

Comment: Even if you have more columns, you should normalize your tables so you don't repeat the same relations like that. The ID->FirstName relationship should be in another table, where they're unique. This way, you won't have to use a subquery like in Gordon Linoff's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A version with `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT t2.FirstName, COUNT(*) Occurrences 
  FROM Table1 t1 JOIN 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT id, firstname
    FROM Table2
) t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
 GROUP BY t2.ID, t2.FirstName
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 4
```

Output:

```
| FIRSTNAME | OCCURRENCES |
---------------------------
|       Mat |           5 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bde9/8)** demo

Comment: Since you're not aggregating Table 2, `COUNT(*)` will be multiplied by the duplicates in that table.

Comment: @Barmar Fair enough. Thanks for pointing that out. Updated the answer.

Comment: Great. It should be outside. It's an alias for the inner subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You want to join to the second table to get the name:

```
SELECT t1.ID , COUNT(t1.OrderID), min(t2.name) as name
FROM Table1 t1 join
     (select id, min(name) as name
      from Table2 t2
      group by id
     ) t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.ID
HAVING COUNT(t1.OrderID) > 4;
```

Before doing the join, though, you need to aggregate by `id` to ensure that there are no duplicates.  The subquery gets the minimum name on an `id`.  If all names are the same, this will be the name.  Otherwise, it is an arbitrary name assigned to the `id`.

EDIT:

You can do the query without subqueries, but I'm not sure that will be more efficient:

```
SELECT t1.ID , COUNT(distinct t1.OrderID), min(t2.name) as name
FROM Table1 t1 join
     Table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.ID
HAVING COUNT(distinct t1.OrderID) > 4;
```

This may look simpler, but it can be much worse in terms of performance.  For instance, if one id had 1000 matches in both table 1 and table 2, then that id would end up with 1,000,000 rows to process after the join.